# Series of consecutive actions

Tags: grammar, tenses, sequence-of-tenses

Hello I have a question about sequence of tenses.

This is my sentence:

"I put my keys down before closing the door, head to the the kitchen and grab something to eat"

My question is : shall I use the -ing form for all verbs that come after "before"?

Comment: Because 'put' can be present tense, either is grammatical. I'd say "I put my keys down before closing the door, headed to the the kitchen and grabbed something to eat" sounds best if that's what you mean here.

Comment: Why/how do you want to use the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Someone else has (I think) provided the same answer I am about to offer. This is a challenging question with a subtlety. Suppose your intent is to tell the reader what **you typically do each day**. Then you would write:

*I put my keys down before closing the door, heading to the kitchen and grabbing something to eat.*

As another poster has indicated, "put" can be in the present tense.

On the other hand, if your intent is to describe **a single completed action in the past**, you would write (I believe):

*I put my keys down before closing the door, headed to the kitchen and grabbed something to eat.*

Comment: Yes, this is all correct. I would add that the original sentence can also be correct, if you are narrating your actions as they happen. This is the traditional style for describing a (literal, nighttime) dream, for example, and is also common in some modern first-person narratives, especially in the YA genre (personally, that style makes me shudder—but I'm not a young adult).

Comment: Excellent point - I had not thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

No, adding "-ing" to the verbs after "before"?, will make the sentence in present continuous tense. So the correct sentence will be:

"I put my keys down before closing the door, headed to the the kitchen and grabbed something to eat"